# Typescript is Unable to Set Conditional Optional Boolean Value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to assign a Boolean value that by default is equal to `true` but can be conditional depending on whether the actual Boolean Value exists in a `props` object or not, like this

```
// default boolean to true
let valid:boolean = true;

if(self.props.hasOwnProperty("valid")) {
    // a property has been specified so use that instead
    valid = self.props.valid;
}
```

`self.props.valid` is an optional parameter but I am getting the following error :

```
TS2322: Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

How can I get the conditional assignment to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's optional, its value may be `undefined`, which you can't assign to a `boolean` variable. `hasOwnProperty` won't help because optional properties are allowed to be present with the value `undefined`.

You can use a different type guard:

```typescript
if (self.props.valid !== undefined) { // Or `if (typeof self.props.valid !== "udnefined"`
    valid = self.props.valid;
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGdldgAuRAb2wCc5sjKrEA3dXGAEwH5KAjOHHzowAbkQBfSQEpqAKERLEAehWIuyYOhC4oiQcOSjEUOKdohki5fn3tOXcoZFIAvBatj5NpTGCIxKTAAHR0DEQhDtyIAIRuHuCawDBgyFxyVL7KSmqI6Ijh2Mi0UACeiAAW6EQGyMhIRMUQ-jDpiETmICSm1fqpRFDGXNk50VyIHiRkYfSMURzc3jmS8qtAA)

Or you could use nullish coalescing:

```typescript
valid = self.props.valid ?? valid;
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGdldgAuRAb2wCc5sjKrEA3dXGAEwH5KAjOHHzowAbkQBfSQEpqAKERLEAehWIuyYOhC4oiQcOSjEUOKdohki5fn3tOXcoZFIAvBatj5NpQ+6IHiRkAHR0DEQh-lyIPDxsHNzekvJAA)

That only changes the value if `self.props.valid` isn't `undefined`.

You could even do that when defining `valid` originally:

```typescript
let valid:boolean = self.props.valid ?? true;
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGdldgAuRAb2wCc5sjKrEA3dXGAEwH5KAjOHHzowAbkQBfSQEpqAKERLE+KGw7dyg4clGIAvIhJkAdHQZET7Tl0Q8eiKLRDIx8yfKA)

Comment: I feel as though this answer will be of the most benefit to others that may come to check in on this so I will accept it as correct

Answer (score 1):

You defined `valid` as only a boolean not `boolean | undefined`

So you either

```
let valid:boolean | undefined = true;

if(self.props.hasOwnProperty("valid")) {
    valid = self.props.valid; // possible undefined is introduced here
}
```

or

```
let valid:boolean = true;

if(self.props.hasOwnProperty("valid")) {
    valid = self.props.valid ?? true // also could be the variable valid
    // this was valid is never undefined
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `hasOwnProperty` doesn't really help here, since the property can be present with the value `undefined`.

Comment: This answer solves my problem as well and I wish I could chose more than one as correct!

Comment: No problem bro, glad to help !

Answer (score 0):

TS cannot tell the property already exists by looking at the if condition. Tell the compiler that you know the property exists :

```
let valid:boolean = true;

interface propsInterface {
  valid? : boolean
}

let props : propsInterface = {
  valid : false
}


if(props.hasOwnProperty("valid")) {
    // a property has been specified so use that instead
    valid = props.valid!;
}
```

Since you have already checked in your code. You can add the [`non null assertion operator`](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/non-null-assertion-operator.html).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCWATAXAIwPbtDAdhAvBGAE4CuIA3ALABQt8OYIxAZjAMYgQAOx63AZwCSjZm04QA3rQjQ4SAPwRkEDFhC5aAX1q1QkXvwHKefQSKasOXQtJqzYCRCbbABIbbro14LABSGggB0ABYwAgDyAO44AApmzGAAnn4ARI5IqQCUWVIyshAA9IUQMKb8iUkQYcaoICB4Atwg7L7wIM4C6BCk7kRhkAwCTDCI+Q7yzoSBAkEZiACE1DRaQA)

Comment: With the above, the OP knows the property exists, but doesn't know whether it contains a boolean. An optional property can contain `undefined`. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGdldgAuRAb2wCc5sjKrEA3dXGAEwH5KAjOHHzowAbkQBfSQEpqAKERLE+KGw7cBQkUgC8iKLRDIxi5TGCJipYADo6DIrYAW6IgHkA7mAAK9bMi0UACeBABE7JxcYTJyVGbKygD0SYjoiA4BQcGIrkSI-MjISEQBEBYwyFyIRHCIICQGrmowYERQyOhcCYnqUYj6JGT2-k6R3ACEpr3KEAi1+La4cADmBONcMhIp9WBcyMCtVYgAtCeIQowTPZLyt2hYeIQ0o8wblOD7h2BV0ltAA) Also, in general, avoid type assertions. :-)